# What is the error "dsfont.sty" in beamer?

Tags: fonts

I am using beamer and I am getting error "dsfont.sty". I do not know how to solve that. I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and Kile. I appreciate your assistance in this regard.

Comment: What is the error message exactly? is it unable to locate the .sty file? if so, it appears to be provide by the `texlive-fonts-extra` package

Answer (score 1):

This file is contained in `texlive-fonts-extra` package (see [search results on packages.ubuntu.com for reference](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=dsfont.sty)).

So you need to install the package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```